# jQuery: How to get ID of dynamically generated element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here's the rundown:

I am creating a table dynamically from the results of an AJAX call. To add the rows, I am using the "after" function, seeing as there are certain rows in the table that function as headers.

After I add these rows, I have a quantity box that I would like to make editable. 
I am able to add an event to it, however I can't get the ID of my row ($(this).parent('tr').attr('id') doesn't work - it returns undefined.

How would I go about being able to get the value of the ID for an element that was added after the DOM tree was parsed?

Comment: A regular $('#id') selector will work, regardless of whether the element was added dynamically.  If you can you show us some code/markup, then it will be easier to help you with the correct selector/traversal to get the element.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code, I wonder if your `$(this)` is in the wrong context. Oh, and `.parent()` only looks for a parent immediately above, another guess is that `.parents()` would be a better bet.

Comment: I believe it would help to see the code to determine how you are adding the element.

Comment: My apologies for the french id's :P 
$('#repas'+data2[index].repas).after('<tr id="'+index+'"><td class="tabRepasContent"> ...');
The $('#id') selector doesn't work, because I need to get the ID from the editbox itself. Just trying to get the id using a link in the same context as follows: 
        $('.linkQuantite').live('click', function(event){             
            alert($(this).parent('tr').attr('class'));            
            event.preventDefault();
        });

Comment: Is the `.linkQuantite` element a child of the `<tr>` element? Does it work when you do `$(this).parent('tr').attr('class'));`?

Comment: The .linkQuantite is a child of the tr element. $(this).parent('tr').attr('class') doesn't work. That's precisely the thing I need to get working, but i'm unsure how to go about doing it because the DOM tree isn't re-parsed by jquery when it calls any events (which is precisely my problem). I could get IDs of things that are there only at pageload

Comment: Are you able to use Firebug to inspect the DOM after you've inserted your elements, can you post the HTML that gets generated after you've inserted a few `<tr>` elements.

Comment: are you able to see id for the <tr> using firebug?

Comment: `$(this).parent('tr').attr('id')` should work, please provide some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`parent('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) returns only the **direct** parent. To be a **direct** child of a `<tr>`, the `this` should be a `<td>`. But the `.linkQuantite` seems to be an `<a>` element. This is definitely not a direct child of `<tr>`. You would rather like to use [`parents('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) or better [`closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for this. The key difference is that `parents('tr')` returns *all* parents matching `'tr'` while `closest('tr')` returns only the *first* parent matchnig `'tr'`.

Comment: Thank you BalusC, I can't believe it was as simple as using parents isntead of parent.. I thought parent() had that functionality.. thanks again

Comment: Just like I suggested 20 minutes ago, beautiful.

Comment: One word of warning about using parents() is that if you have nested tables, you will get a collection of all table cells that are in the parent hierarchy. closest(), if you're using a recent version of jQuery, will be better and faster, and ensure that you're only getting the closest parent tr.

Comment: @jmar: That's exactly why I said that `closest('tr')` is better. The `parents('tr')` returns **all** parents matching `'tr'`.

Comment: @BalusC: Right - I was agreeing. I was just providing the reasoning behind the assertion that .closest() was better here, in case the OP isn't as familiar with the jQuery API.

Comment: @jmar: ah yes, I see, thanks :) I extended the answer with the key difference explanation anyway.