# Returning id from Ajax generated DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know there is a duplicate ([jQuery: How to get ID of dynamically generated element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493730/jquery-how-to-get-id-of-dynamically-generated-element)) but I tried the solution and I couldn't fix my problem.

An ajax/jquery query has returned a table which when inspected returns a properly formed table:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Example</td><td class="del" id="1">Delete</td></tr>
<tr><td>Example2</td><td class="del" id="2">Delete</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The jquery code is:

```
$('.del').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
```

If I put the table directly in the HTML it works fine however when it it generated from the ajax it doesn't even generate an alert (and chrome doesn't return an error).

NB I appologise in advance if it is something stupid like a misnamed id but I have been trying to figure this out for 3/4 hour and am stuck!

## **Edit:**

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({type : 'POST', url : 'response.php'}).done(function(response){
        $('#result').html(response);
    });
```

Comment: you have to wait until the element exists before you bind a click event to it.

Comment: delegate event using .on()

Comment: @KevinB How can I do this (do I need another $(document).ready()  inside?)

Comment: Study up on *"event delegation"* so that you have a general understanding of how it works, then look at the delegation features of jQuery methods, like `.on()`.

Comment: which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo on here, will edit

Comment: @roasted: That's actually valid HTML4/5. Though probably a good idea to include them.

Comment: @CrazyTrain You mean not closing `<tr>` tags is HTML valid?

Comment: @roasted: Correct, if we're talking about HTML4 and 5. There are a number of elements where the closing *(and sometimes opening)* tag is optional under certain situations. Not for XHTML though.

Comment: @CrazyTrain That's nice, i learn something new today even i'll never not close a `<tr>` it's still good to know, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your javascript as follows

```
$(document).on("click", ".del", function(){ 
var id = $(this).attr("id");
alert(id);
 });        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Please refer to following article for detail
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: live() has been removed from some time now

Comment: and doesn't exist in jQuery 2.0.3, which was mentioned as the current version being used in the comments.

Comment: please read carefully i have provided all possible variations, available in different versions.

Comment: A careful reading of your answer will indicate that `.live()` works with `jQuery 1.3+`, which isn't quite accurate.

Comment: Then i believe we need to request jquery guys to correct their documentation. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Why? The docs you linked state `version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9`

Comment: i am not saying that its still valid to use for new version of jquery, since question is related with version 2.0.3 .live is still relevant.

Comment: How's that? It was removed in `1.9` and `2.0.3` is greater than `1.9`.

Comment: :-) Just may want to update your docs link to point to the `on` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is using delegation, i'd suggest to use that instead of setting multiple handlers for each new created elements.

```
$(document).on('click','.del',function(){
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    });
```

Use the closest static container instead of document as delegate target would be better but i don't know your code...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K6rbp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use load function which evals all the loaded js from server. 
Use `$("#id").load(<url>,<callback of success>);` instead

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: How does this help with event handling for the newly created elements?

Comment: In general would this be preferable to get() post() and ajax()?

Comment: No, it is not preferable with respect to get() post() and ajax().
Using on is also better option.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the ajax call? How is it structured?

Depending on your ajax call, you can put the function in a callback, and it will attach to the element then.